# Unable to restore TDE enabled database when MAXTRANSFERSIZE and CHECKSUM is used

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2016, transparent-data-encryption

**Update**: [@AmitBanerjee](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/63343/amit-banerjee) - Senior Program Manager for the Microsoft SQL Server Product Group confirmed that MS will look into the issue as [it is a defect.](https://twitter.com/banerjeeamit/status/811399144552087552)

Has anyone encountered issue restoring backups taken on SQL Server 2016 with TDE enabled and using `MAXTRANSFERSIZE` > 65536 (in my case, I have chosen 65537 so that [I can compress TDE database](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2016/06/20/sqlsweet16-episode-1-backup-compression-for-tde-enabled-databases/)) and `CHECKSUM` ?

Below is a repro:

```
--- create database 
create database test_restore
go
-- create table
create table test_kin (fname char(10))
go
-- Enable TDE 

use master
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE test_restore WITH SUBJECT = 'test_restore_cert'
GO
SELECT name, pvt_key_encryption_type_desc, * FROM sys.certificates WHERE name = 'test_restore'
GO
use test_restore
go
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128 ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE test_restore
GO 
alter database test_restore set encryption ON
```

Take full copy only backup .. do it twice ..

```
backup database test_restore 
to disk = 'D:\temporary-short-term\test_restore_KIN_test_restore_1.bak' -- change as per your location !!
with init, stats =10  -- overwrite ..using INIT !!
, maxtransfersize = 65537
, compression
,CHECKSUM
```

Now do a `verifyonly` ...

```
restore verifyonly from disk = 'D:\temporary-short-term\test_restore_KIN_test_restore_1.bak'
```

Error Message :

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 40, Line 11
>   The media family on device 'D:\temporary-short-term\test_restore_KIN_test_restore_1.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

**Results (1 = ON, 0 = OFF) with different combinations :**

```
+-------------------------+-------------+----------+--------+
| MAXTRANSFERSIZE (65537) | COMPRESSION | CHECKSUM | RESULT |
+-------------------------+-------------+----------+--------+
|                       1 |           1 |        1 | FAIL   |
|                       1 |           1 |        0 | PASS   |
|                       1 |           0 |        1 | FAIL   |
|                       0 |           0 |        0 | PASS   |
|                       0 |           1 |        1 | PASS   |
|                       0 |           1 |        0 | PASS   |
+-------------------------+-------------+----------+--------+
```

The issue happens on:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-CU1) (KB3164674) - 13.0.2149.0 (X64)   Jul 11 2016 22:05:22   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem.

Adding `FORMAT` to the `BACKUP` command solved it for me.

While I can't seem to find concrete documentation, it's my opinion that this is related to the fact that `INIT` retains the existing media header on the backup set while `FORMAT` creates a new media header.

I'm still researching this issue and if I find additional information, I will update this answer.

Comment: yep, the `FORMAT` will overwrite header as well and it does not happen when using `FORMAT`. Still this is a mystery as why the backup header (or backup as a whole) gets corrupted when using `MAXTRANSFERSIZE` and `CHECKSUM` together along with INIT. This never happened on lower versions but in those there was no `MAXTRANSFERSIZE` . Thanks for your answer. Will keep this open if someone has more info.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this might have been addressed with KB 4032200:

- [FIX: Fail to compress the backup file when INIT and COMPRESSION option is used in a TDE enabled database in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032200/fix-fail-to-compress-the-backup-file-when-init-and-compression-option)

From that entry:

> ### Symptoms
>
> Assume that you enable Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) for a database in Microsoft SQL Server 2016. You try to backup the database by using the **`BACKUP DATABASE`** T-SQL statement that has both **`COMPRESSION`** and **`INIT`** option specified. In this scenario, you may notice that the existing backup file is overwritten by the new backup file, and the new backup file is not compressed.
>
> ### Resolution
>
> This issue is fixed in the following cumulative updates for SQL Server:
>
> - [Cumulative Update 7 for SQL Server 2016 RTM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4024304)
> - [Cumulative Update 4 for SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4024305)

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to potentially be the same issue that the [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2016/06/20/sqlsweet16-episode-1-backup-compression-for-tde-enabled-databases/) you referenced in your question was later updated to refer to:

> #### *Update April 6th, 2017*
>
> *We have recently discovered some issues related to the use of TDE and backup compression in SQL Server 2016. While we fix them, here are some tips to help you avoid running into those known issues:*
>
> - *Currently it is not advisable to use striped backups with TDE and backup compression*
> - *If your database has virtual log files (VLFs) larger than 4GB then do not use backup compression with TDE for your log backups. If you don’t know what a VLF is, start [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2012/02/22/too-many-virtual-log-files-vlfs-can-cause-slow-database-recovery/).*
> - *Avoid using WITH INIT for now when working with TDE and backup compression. Instead, for now you can use WITH FORMAT.*
>
> *SQL engineering is working on fixes for these issues in SQL Server 2016. We will update this blog post once again once we have further information to share.*

Despite that note, the blog post has not been updated with any further information since then.

However, [KB 4019893](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019893/fix-restore-fails-when-you-do-backup-by-using-compression-and-checksum) may also address this:

- [FIX: Restore fails when you do backup by using compression and checksum on a TDE enabled database in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019893/fix-restore-fails-when-you-do-backup-by-using-compression-and-checksum)

Although the error message reported in that KB article is different than the one you are reporting, the contributing factors sound very similar. SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU3 first included the fix, as seen in its [hotfix list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019916/cumulative-update-3-for-sql-server-2016-sp1#kb-link-123). However, [there have been reports](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/tde-backup-compression-together-last/#comment-2427725) that it did not resolve the issue in all situations.

SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU4 also [includes a (presumably updated) fix for this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4024305/cumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2016-sp1#kb-link-126), and [KB 4019893](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019893/fix-restore-fails-when-you-do-backup-by-using-compression-and-checksum) has since been updated to show SP1 CU4 as the version the issue was fixed in.

**Unfortunately, I can confirm from my own experience that even the fix in SP1 CU4 does not fully resolve that issue.** I currently have one TDE-enabled database that still produces consistently corrupt backups even on SP1 CU4 when using `COMPRESSION` (via `MAXTRANSFERSIZE` > 64 KB) and `CHECKSUM`. I also have several dozen other TDE-enabled databases in this environment that consistently *don't* produce corrupt backups under those settings, including one that is a variation of the one that does, with a nearly identical schema but smaller dataset. This would seem to indicate that Microsoft is indeed chipping away at the scenarios that can cause this, but has not resolved all of them yet.

I've not yet tried using `FORMAT` to work around this issue, as referenced in another answer and the SQLCAT [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2016/06/20/sqlsweet16-episode-1-backup-compression-for-tde-enabled-databases/), but I'll provide an update here if I'm able to try that and it resolves the issue. The one database I have that reproduces this is unfortunately rather large (~1 TB), and resides in a Development / QA cluster that doesn't have much extra storage space available (at least at that scale), so testing variations of this has proven to be logistically challenging and time-consuming.

Comment: This issue still exists in SQL 2017.