# Using Ola Hallengren’s Maintenance in SQL Server 2016 with TDE Enabled databases and compression

Tags: sql-server-2016, compression, ola-hallengren

I’m using Ola Hallengren’s maintenance and backup solution and looking into leveraging TDE compression as I have all the databases in instance using TDE  impression. Is there a way of getting benefit of TDE compression with Ola’s solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Ola's SQL Server Maintenance Solution Version History](https://ola.hallengren.com/versions.html)
(highlighting mine)

> 25 Sep 2016
>
> Improved handling of databases with Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)
>   together with backup compression. If you have databases with TDE in
>   SQL Server 2014 and earlier, backup compression is not used. **If you
>   have databases with TDE in SQL Server 2016, backup compression is used
>   if MAXTRANSFERSIZE is greater than 65536**.

You should make sure that you can restore these compressed backups.  There were some problems as referenced by this Stack Exchange post ([Unable to restore TDE enabled database when MAXTRANSFERSIZE and CHECKSUM is used](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158632/60085))